# co-variance using Arrays.asList in java?

Tags: java, list, types

When I create a list, I hope to initialize it eagerly; so I used `Arrays.asList`. However it seems that it is not covariant as to inheritance.

For example,

```
List<NameValuePair> p = Arrays.asList(new BasicNameValuePair("c", coin), new BasicNameValuePair("mk_type", fromCoin));
```

doesn't work (`BasicNameValuePair` is a derived class of `NameValuePair`).

While it OK to use `add` as usual.

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", coin));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mk_type", fromCoin));
```

Since the library API only accepts `List<NameValuePair>` type as its argument, I have to define `pairs` this way. Is there any way to deal with this issue elegantly?

Comment: @bayou.io: while I accept that it works, I cannot understand why.  Generics, unlike arrays, have never been covariant in Java. The dogma was that arrays are covariant and reified; generics are invariant and erased.  A `List<Subtype>` is never supposed to be a subtype of `List<ParentType>`.

Comment: @scottb -  in java5-7, type inference on this case only looks at argument types.   Java8 improves type inference and considers more constraints, in this case, the assignment type; `<NameValuePair>` is inferred for `asList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, then I believe you could use an explicit<sup>1</sup> generic type in the method call to `Arrays.asList` like

```
List<NameValuePair> p = Arrays.<NameValuePair>asList(new BasicNameValuePair(
        "c", coin), new BasicNameValuePair("mk_type", fromCoin));
```

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>[Generic Methods (The Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to give it a generic hint:

```
List<NameValuePair> p = Arrays.<NameValuePair>asList(new BasicNameValuePair("c", coin), new BasicNameValuePair("mk_type", fromCoin));
```